# Setting errorType flag using assert module in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, error-handling, assert

I like [assert](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) module of [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/).
I use following sysntax hevyily.

```
var assert = require('assert')
var l = [1, 2, 3]
var x = 2
assert(l.indexOf(x) < 0, "you are in list blacklisted numbers")
```

In this code if `x` is 3 then I will see error that its blacklisted case. So I want to set errorType to some value. How can I do this using assert module? Currently I am doing using `if/else`

```
if (!(l.indexOf(x) < 0)) {
   var errorType = 1
   assert(false, "you are in list blacklisted numbers")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create custom error like this

```
var assert = require('assert')

class ErrorType extends Error {
    constructor(message, code) {
        super(message)
        this.name = this.constructor.name
        this.code = code
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    }
}


try {
    var l = [1, 2, 3]
    var x = 2
    assert(l.indexOf(x) < 0, new ErrorType("you are in list blacklisted numbers", 1234))
} catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ErrorType) {
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log("normal error")
    }
}
```